# The upcoming leap second and SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, date-time

Is there any known issues when a leap second occurs? Leap years seems to be fine but i have yet to find any information related to leap seconds and how it could possibly have any impact on SharePoint.

For those who don't know what a leap second is, see below article from Wikipedia.

> A leap second is a one-second adjustment that is occasionally applied to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) in order to keep its time of day close to the mean solar time, or UT1. Without such a correction, time reckoned by Earth's rotation drifts away from atomic time because of irregularities in the Earth's rate of rotation. Since this system of correction was implemented in 1972, 25 such leap seconds have been inserted. The most recent one happened on June 30, 2012 at 23:59:60 UTC. A leap second, the 26th, will again be inserted at the end of June 30, 2015 at 23:59:60 UTC.
>
> Specifically, a positive leap second is inserted between second 23:59:59 of a chosen UTC calendar date (the last day of a month, usually June 30 or December 31) and second 00:00:00 of the following date. This extra second is displayed on UTC clocks as 23:59:60. On clocks that display local time tied to UTC, the leap second may be inserted at the end of some other hour (or half-hour or quarter-hour), depending on the local time zone.

[Leap Seconds - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)

It is about to happen very soon ( 2015-06-30 ) and i wonder if there are any known SharePoint related problems that may occur?

Do anyone have any experience with earlier leap seconds or did anyone ever experienced any problems with critical services like timer jobs, any custom workflows or just the whole servers going nuts that could relate to this?